# Crash with PDFKit on iOS 12.2

Tags: ios, pdfview

In iOS 12.2, passing `true` to `PDFView`'s `usePageViewController(_, withViewOptions:)` will cause a crash with the following exception:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan nan]'

The same code works fine on iOS 12.1. I also have other projects that do this and those projects *do* work on iOS 12.2, but their view controller hierarchy is quite a bit more complicated.

Is there possibly something I'm missing, or should I file a bug report with Apple?

I have created a tiny project on github which demonstrates the crash at https://github.com/rudedogdhc/crash-pdfview-ios12.2

Comment: Why would I want to comment that line? That just gives me a black screen because the app no longer has a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `usePageViewController(_, withViewOptions:)` (and everything else you're setting up with it for that matter) into `viewDidAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`

I ran into the same problem and found the answer here: [There's problem with PDFKit appeared after update to Xcode 10.2. Is there any way to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362754/theres-problem-with-pdfkit-appeared-after-update-to-xcode-10-2-is-there-any-wa)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. He posted his question literally a minute before I posted mine.